# How to make package visible to PHP in Linux?

Tags: php, linux, nginx, phalcon, fpm

I uninstalled `phalcon7.4-phalcon4` and installed `php-phalcon4` package in **Linux (Debian GNU/Linux 11)**. But I can't see phalcon in `phpinfo();`.  Should I register package in fpm `php.ini` file? If yes how can I do this?

I restarted `php-fpm` and `nginx` after installation. I am using `Ondřej Surý` repo to install package. See [Docs](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/installation#linux)

**Instructions that I followed in docs:**

[image: Instructions I followed]

**How I installed package:**

[image: Package installation]

**Edit:**

I just realized my server missing `phalcon.so` file which should be created after package installation. Is there any way to generate it manually?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't fully install the package on linux otherwise it would be visible. And `linux` can mean a lot of different things in this context, e.g. which package manager did you use, what is the distribution, what is the package repository? And to which documentation/installation instructions are you referring to? And last but not least, the [tag:phalcon] tag was missing - I edited it in.

Comment: @hakre thanks for response. You can check edited answer

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code/commands and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see _[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500)_ and _[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)_ for why. For instructions on formatting see _[How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)_.

Comment: And if you're using the sury packages, have you already found out where the PHP configuration files are located (as well for php-fpm)? Those are `.ini` files (phpinfo() should give you a hint). Each extension should have its own .ini, make yourself comfortable with that system and then check with the php documentation how to enable extensions - as this could be the cause. The main php.ini also contains documentation in form of comments for each directive in use (or suggested for use).

Comment: There is not many lines of code to present in snipped. I shared one image from docs for which I already gave link and another shows 1 line of terminal code that I executed and server response. My question it quite clear and understandable to everyone. If you are not able to help me to solve my issue then please stop giving me instructions about using stackoverflow.

Comment: @hakre I already know location of php `config` and `ini` files. But I don't know how to find `ini` file of extension.

Comment: Please don't complain to me, it's just that screenshots aren't that accepted, I didn't want to tell you that you did something wrong, just what you should do to improve the question to match the community guidelines. That is a bit more than whether or not what someone thinks if it is understandable or clear. That is often in the eye of the beholder and it's just that here on site the textual form is preferred, even for non-code, e.g. shell command examples, quotes from documentation pages etc. .

Comment: Locate the ini directory for php-fpm and look inside there. You should see a couple of files in the directory listing which all have extension names in the file-name. You may need to create one for phalcon, I don't know, it may already exist. Check that, then verify the configuration by that file if the extension is enabled. I'm sure you get this done then.

Comment: @hakre I found extension's ini file but `phalcon.so` file is not generated in `/usr/lib/php`. I don't know why but is there any way to generate it manually?

Comment: perhaps it is better to first search it on disk before actually compiling the shared object - which is possible but can benefit from practice and also you would give up one of the benefits using the package manager as it provides this binary already.

Answer (score 0):

These may need to be tweaked, but here are the commands I used to install Phalcon 4:

```
mkdir /usr/local/lib/php7.4
cd /usr/local/lib/php7.4
git clone --branch v4.1.2 https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
cd cphalcon/build
sudo ./install --phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.4 --php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.4
phpenmod phalcon
```

I would try the command in the 4.0 installation instructions on phalcon.io first, and they don't work for you, you can try my commands above.

FYI, the commands for Phalcon 5.0 are different, so make sure you are on the proper page for Phalcon 4.

Comment: I have already installed phalcon 4 actually. But I need to change the package I installed, because it was giving 502 bad gateway error in each request. I solved my problem by reinstalling same package and restarting fpm. Anyway, your support appreciated.